# Android: when wrap_content doesn't just wrap its content?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a following xml layout in my project (incidentally, if you notice something else that is also seemingly wrong/not so good yet, I'd appreciate you let me know about it!) and my problem is the attribute "wrap_contents" doesn't work at the last TextView ("EEE", txt4). Is there any regulation I overlook?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/Table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="AAA"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spn1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:entries="@array/array1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="BBB"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:entries="@array/Tounyuhou" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="CCC" android:textColor="@color/white" 
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="DDD"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

            </EditText>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="EEE"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it "doesn't work"?  What are you seeing and what were you expecting to see?

Comment: just give a colored background to the view for which you think "it doesn't work".

Comment: @JerseyMike by that, I meant, why txt4's width wasn't just the required length to wrap the text 'EEE'? Sorry if it's vague.

Comment: @Akki In the original XML, most View had drawables, but I removed 'em for the sake of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you define all the rows in same layout , but with different number of views, like row1 contain 2 , row2 contain 4 then row3 contain 3 views,

so it gives problem,

so my suggetion take different tablelayout for third row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/mainTable_tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/Table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="AAA"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />


                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spn1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/array1" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/edt1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="BBB"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spn2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/Tounyuhou" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="CCC" android:textColor="@color/white" 
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>

            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
                android:id="@+id/mainTable_tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/Table2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table2_tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="DDD"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />



                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

                </EditText>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="EEE"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

            </TableRow>


            </TableLayout>
</TableRow>
 </TableLayout>

    </merge>
```

Comment: Thanks, if I copied and pasted yours, the second tableLayout seems to be over-layered on the first. Should I use a parents layout for them?

Comment: here i have edit the above answer so, try it your problem definetly solved.